# Not able to install CollabNet 6.1.1 TeamForge 32 bit on my Windows

Tags: collabnet

I have downloaded the latest version 6.1.1 from the windows installer for 32bit. I have a problem with the installation. The installer checks for software requierements are fulfilled. Out of 4 programs it installs i.e. msys, java, postgre and CsvnEdge, csvnEdge is marked as not installed. Tough in system i can see it is installed. If I cancel the setup and start again, it fails again to find CsvnEdge.

Regards
Anuj
[image]